# Teradata SQL - how to get data between current month and current month+8 (current month+8 will fall into 2023)

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have this code but returns 0 row:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM POST_DATE)
FROM
MY_TABLE

WHERE

EXTRACT(MONTH FROM POST_DATE) BETWEEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,8))
```

Now it's month 5, and if my code changes to 7 instead 8, the result is showing 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.
And MY_TABLE has data for 2023.
Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Date between 01/'"this month" and end of month( today + 8 months)

Comment: thanks for comments,  can you write it in codes pls? I'm fairly new to SQL. thank you

Comment: See answer. I do not have access to Teradata. Please check my query. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we calculate the first day of this month, then we add 9 months to the last day of last month.

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM POST_DATE)
FROM
MY_TABLE
WHERE POST_DATE BETWEEN
  ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1, 0)
AND
  ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE), 9)
;
```